# How will MySql handle an Update that uses the field-to-be-updated in other parts of the query?

Tags: mysql

So say I have the following statement:

```
UPDATE time_tracking_table 
SET `end` = NOW(), `duration` = TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(`end`,`start`)) 
WHERE `end` > NOW()
```

What I am trying to achieve is the following (using 10pm as an example for `NOW()`): "*find all rows where `end` is later then 10pm, then update `end` for that row and set it to 10pm, then calculate the difference between the `start` of that row and it's new value (10pm) as the `duration`*".

I have been testing the above query for a few days and it seems to work. My question is:

**a)** Is it reliable (or is there some sort of race condition involved here considering the simultaneous update of `end` and use of `end` in the `where` and `timediff`) and...

**b)** Even if it does work, is there perhaps a better way to achieve this?

Many thanks in advance for your time and expertise!

Comment: I don't know whether it's called multiple times or not but if you are worried about different calls to NOW doing different things then you might consider writing a stored procedure that calls it only once. Also I think NOW() is dependent on the server time zone; for some purposes (not necessarily yours) UTC_TIMESTAMP() is better.

Comment: The `WHERE` clause will *always* use the *original* value of `end`.  As for the `SET` clause (for `duration`), since you *know* what `end` is going to be couldn't you do: `duration = TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(NOW(), start))`?

Comment: I believe it is an official behavior, not an undocumented one, that the value used in later field sets is the one set in earlier ones (most "recent") of the same update, not the original value. I.E. `SET x = 1, y = x` will always result in y being set to 1; `SET x=1, x=2, y=x` will always result in y == 2.

Comment: @RocketHazmat Thanks! that pretty much settles it :)

Comment: @Uueerdo good to know!

Comment: @Hammerite You don't need a stored procedure, just join with a subquery that does `(SELECT @now := NOW())` and use `@now` in the rest of the query.

Comment: @Uueerdo That would violate the SQL Standard. `SET x=y, y = x` should swap the column values not set them both to y.

Comment: @MartinSmith I can confirm (just now tested), in MySQL it works as I described; in MSSQL, it acts as a swap.

Comment: @Uueerdo thanks for the info!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the MySQL [docs on `UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html)...

> The second assignment in the following statement sets col2 to the
>   current (updated) col1 value, not the original col1 value. The result
>   is that col1 and col2 have the same value. This behavior differs from
>   standard SQL.
>
> ```
> UPDATE t1 SET col1 = col1 + 1, col2 = col1;
> ```

Comment: This is a part answer but doesn't (claerly) define if the same applies to the WHERE clause

Comment: @Martin True, I just skimmed the update docs a little more thoroughly and they don't explicitly say it; it is probably considered obvious since only rows that match get updated, and it wouldn't make sense to "un-update" them if the `set` changed values. Everything in the docs points to `where` being evaluated first though.

Comment: I did consider that after I commented that, as you say, the `WHERE` will always be processed first. `:-D`